# SQL Server Web transaction replication to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

In [Features for SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Anchor_4), I see that Transactional replication to Azure is supported for Web edition. [Following the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-using-transactional-replication) leads to [Configure Publishing and Distribution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms151192.aspx#Anchor_2)

In attempting to create the publication, I get `This edition of SQL Server cannot act as a Publisher or Distributor for replication.`, which is expected as my server is Web edition.

So how do I set up Web edition replication to Azure SQL, given that it is a supported feature?

Answer (score 1):

According to Xiaochen Wu (Senior Program Manager at Microsoft), there is an error in the documentation. [Web edition does not support transaction replication to Azure SQL.](http://disq.us/p/1d3hif0)